# What is the best way to monitor performance of an AWS server from a C# program?

Tags: c#, performance, amazon-web-services, wmi, snmp

I want to monitor from home, from my own C# program, my own AWS network. I have already work and achieve some progress with SNMP but not sure if is the best tool for this job.

I can think in several possible ways to measure performance, but not sure which one is the best?
(By best I mean mainly more easy to develop and more up to date)

1. **Develop my own C# performance monitor**: Reinventing the wheel?
2. **SNMP**: I have already tried this but not sure if it is the best approach.
3. **WMI**: Not sure if it is possible...
4. **AWS SDK API**: Maybe is possible from here?

So my question is:

**What is the best way to measure performance? Is there any other option?**

Comment: You do know, that there are lots of applications just for that? Including open source and free ones. I personally like PRTG, and it has a free licence for small networks.

Comment: Thanks I know but I need it from C# (I am evolving a Uni project) :) What I have now is my C# communicating standard windows SNMP agent but I have the impression that SNMP is not the best thing...

Comment: What type of performance are you trying to mesure? If you are looking at instance utilization, using cloudwatch data is probably the best option.

Comment: I want to measure typical performance counters: Instant CPU load, free memory, bandwidth, etc. Anyways, I didn't knew about CloudWatch data. Will investigate thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a step by step cookbook to get CloudWatch alarms sent to an email address.  I used this procedure to setup getting emails when my Cassandra or Zookeeper servers on AWS would fail.  Here is the link:  http://briantarbox.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-setup-amazon-cloudwatch-to-send.html